# Shopware 6: custom plugin snippets multiline

Tags: json, plugins, shopware6

Shopware [only accept snippets files in `.json` format](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/administration/adding-snippets#creating-snippet-files).

How to handle multine text?

Answer (score 3):

Either use `\\n` for new line or, if the snippet is used in html, `<br>`.

```json
{
  "snippet1": "First line<br>Next line",
  "snippet2": "First line\\nNext line"
}
```

Comment: @dneustadt 
Ok, in js/twig i call then `snippets1 + snippest2 + ...`, but what about if the spanish translation has more `snippet*` than other translations? Sholud i first check the current language each time?

Comment: @tinect at my opinion, it is the same context, but please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75184806/shopware-6-custom-plugin-snippets-with-dynamic-multilines