# Shopware 6: custom plugin snippets with dynamic multilines

Tags: json, plugins, shopware6

Shopware only accept snippets files in .json format.

How to handle multiline text with different number of lines for different translations?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have the different number of lines in each language(For example 10 lines in English and 2 in Spanish), you have to create only one snippet but with different text inside, using line break as @tinect wrote in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/75177091/21048350.

The English version will look like this: "text\ntext\n...\ntext"
and Spanish: "text\ntext"

Comment: Ok, sorry, for a better understanding: Your answer offer a single line in **json** with linebreaks. My question apointed the **multiline** in the **json** file like an array for a better reading (80 chars in code line)

Comment: Okey so it isn't possible. Json [doesn't support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392766/are-multi-line-strings-allowed-in-json/2392888#2392888) multilines strings.